# ffmpeg-python lib's 'run' function works locally but doesn't work in server

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-python

I am using ffmpeg-python library to process video, specifically I had to add watermark to video. Code is very simple:

```
def set_watermark_to_video(
    video_url: str,
    directory: str,
    filename: str,
    extension: str,
):
    video_input = ffmpeg.input(video_url)
    output_path: str = f"/tmp/{filename}_watermarked.mp4"
    logo_input = ffmpeg.input(vid_mycar_logo_path)
    video_probe = ffmpeg.probe(video_url)
    video_stream = next(
        (
            stream
            for stream in video_probe["streams"]
            if stream["codec_type"] == "video"
        ),
        None,
    )

    logo_probe = ffmpeg.probe("my_logo_path")
    logo_stream = next(
        (stream for stream in logo_probe["streams"] if stream["codec_type"] == "video"),
        None,
    )
    ffmpeg.filter(
        [video_input, logo_input],
        "overlay",
        10,
        video_stream["height"] - logo_stream["height"] - 10,
    ).output(output_path).run(overwrite_output=True)
```

Exception occurs when `.run(overwrite_output=True)` function is called.
Exception looks like this: ***ffmpeg._run.Error: ffmpeg error (see stderr output for detail)**.*

When I print exc.stderr the only warning I can see is "***Unknown cover type: 0x1."***

But this code works perfectly when I run it locally. I am using docker to build my service, so dependencies, versions, etc all the same in both environments.

The version of ffmpeg I'm using is `5.1.4-0+deb12u1`

I tried to run code line by line in server and local machine to compare all parameters and values that have been generated. And still they are the same, so I don't understand why this error happens in server

Comment: Can the server properly reach `video_url`? You can try downloading the file separately and then passing a local path instead of an URL to ffmpeg.

Comment: ```video_probe = ffmpeg.probe(video_url)``` function doesn't fail, it would fail if file was unreachable or unreadable @Taavi